# Key modifiers using cases doesn't work?

Tags: c#

I have defined that when a key is down using cases to differentiate various keys an action happens

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.B:
            //something happens here
        break;
    }
}
```

when I try to add a key modifier, for example "Ctrl", I did it like this

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.B && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control:
            //something happens here
        break;
    }
}
```

Edit: It says `'&&' Cannot be applied to operands of type 'Windows.System.Forms.Keys' and 'bool'` when I try to do it like that.

How would it be done correctly?

Comment: `doesn't work` is a hard to understand diagnostic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put the `if` statement as part of the case label.  Case directly compares the constant value in the label to the variable in the switch; the result of a `&&` operator is a `bool`, which cannot be compared to a `KeyEventArg`.  You will need to add it separately or use `if` statements.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.B:
            if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
                //something happens here
            //else
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing wrong?

Absolutely, you are! `case` labels are not conditions, they are values compared to the expression inside the `switch` for equality.

You can put an additional `if` inside each `case` where you need to check other conditions, or use an `if`-`then`-`else` chain:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.B && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control) {
        //something happens here
    } else if (...) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Corrected the question. What I need is the key Modifiers to be used with `case`.

Comment: I know this is windows forms but just mentioning that in WPF KeyEventArgs doesn't have a Modifiers property, you have to use Keyboard.Modifiers instead.

Answer (score 0):

Following from the other answers you could still use a case statement by making a Tuple and checking cases against the hash code since Tuple is a reference type eg.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int hash = new Tuple<Keys, Keys>(e.KeyCode, e.Modifiers).GetHashCode();
    switch (hash)
    {
        case new Tuple<Keys, Keys>(Keys.B, Keys.Control).GetHashCode():
            //something happens here
        break;
    }
}
```